# Pattern in production makes the form field and overall form invalid

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-forms, production, dev-to-production

I am using template driven form in ionic-angular project.

```
<input type="password" ngModel required name="password" pattern="(?=.*\[0-9])(?=.*\[a-z]).{6,}"></input>
```

The above input filed works fine in development mode.But in production it displays as invalid.

The value of the password field is valid if I enter '**aaaaaaa@123**' in development and in production the same value becomes invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove backslash escape characters from your regexp. It should look like this:

```
(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}
```